# triggers or else between 2 postgres databases hosted on a different datacenter

Tags: postgresql, trigger, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create a trigger inside of a Postgres RDS database hosted in Frankfurt that we will call "Frankfurt". That trigger will poll tables in a distant Postgres RDS database hosted in Seoul, let's call that database "Seoul".

The Seoul database will never have delete nor update. It will only have insert.

The aim of that trigger is for each insert into the Seoul database to copy the rows from Seoul that are not in Frankfurt, to the Frankfurt database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_dml_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $employees$
    BEGIN
        --
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            perform dblink_connect('dbname=database_seoul user=postgres password=ExtraPassword'); 
            INSERT INTO all_employees
            SELECT *
            FROM dblink('foreign_server',$RDS$
                SELECT * 
                FROM employees 
                WHERE employee_id NOT IN  (SELECT employee_id FROM all_employees)   
            $RDS$) AS t1;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_dml_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_dml_function();
```

I'm not sure if it is the best way.

Comment: What's the criteria for being "best"? What's _your_ question, actually?

Comment: hi @mustaccio my question is for every line written in the seoul db, I need it to be copied in the Frankfurt db. Best, I'm not sure. Let me change that word.

Comment: I'm not sure which database you're creating the trigger "I'm trying to create a trigger inside of a Postgres RDS database hosted in Frankfurt"... "each insert into the Seoul database"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a good idea, you should read the documentation on [Streaming Synchronous Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/warm-standby.html#synchronous-replication) instead which guarantees consistency and is a ton easier to configure.

Even if you're not going to use that, you should consider [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) instead of the older dblink.

Comment: hi @evan-carroll, will streaming synchronous rep and postgres_fdw work on amazon rds?

Comment: do you know a decent source of documentation on postgres?

Comment: postgres_fdw is certainly on rds https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/rds-postgres-read-replicas/, but no idea on the rest. You'll have to search for it.

Comment: seems postgres_fdw is not possible on rds  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747886/postgres-fdw-cannot-connect-to-server-on-amazon-rds

Comment: one last question @evan-carroll will it be possible to set streaming synchronous rep and use the replica set in Frankfurt data center and use that replica to copy data to the main db?

Comment: @AndyK: "*a decent source of documentation on postgres*" - the manual:

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name #rotfl

Comment: @AndyK you're going to have to evaluate the different types of replication and see which one best suites your needs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/different-replication-solutions.html https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling however as a general rule, rolling your own is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @EvanCarroll synchronous replication is between a master and a number of slaves.  I know that from the wording it's not clear, but Andy wants to write certain inserts on one master to another.

Comment: It seems that there is no synchronous multimaster options for Pg. Regardless, if eventual is enough, the link provided mentions Bucardo which may fit his needs, and or he can check out BDR. And, that's only if he really needs multimaster. I would go there before trying to roll my own solution.